Problems rendering GUI windows in Ubuntu 22.04 over Oracle VirtualBox 7.0.18
I'm using Ubuntu for development and tests. It is installed on a virtual machine over Oracle VirtualBox.
After the first restart of the system, the GUI glitches in synch with the video frame refreshes.
An example can be seen here.

Basic information regarding the VM:

What could be the issue?

I think it's due to low graphics memory, increased to 64MB and until now it's smooth.
I'll update if it's not appropriate yet.

A guest OS in VirtualBox can be configured to use up to 256MB video memory. To increase the video memory to 256MB, make sure the virtual machine you want to modify is completely shut down before running this command.
VBoxManage modifyvm "Name of VM" --vram 256  

For significant 3D acceleration, enabling 3D acceleration features in the virtual machine settings and installing VirtualBox Guest Additions are more crucial. Guest Additions provides a bigger performance boost by utilizing the host machine's graphics card memory.
